# Using mechanize to visit a site that requires SSL

Tags: python, ssl, ssl-certificate, mechanize

I need to visit a site (https://*) that requires me to install two certificates in Firefox before I can visit it successfully. One I can export as a .p12 file (Client Certificate), and one is a .crt file (CA Certificate). If I try accessing this site without these certificates, I get a "failed handshake error".

How do I visit this site in Python? I was thinking of using mechanize. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you use [webdriver](http://code.google.com/p/webdriver/) to automate Firefox. It has a Python interface too.